# Execute function defined in config file

Tags: bash, shell

I´m implememnting a generic bash script where I receive as parameter from my config file a function. Then I just want to execute that function.

My config file contains.

```
  downloadFunction="curl -s 'https://foo.com/foo.jar' -o '/bla.jar'"
```

Then in the main bash file I try this two thnigs

```
   # load config
   . ${script_dir}/configs/${config}/config || exit 1

    exec bash -c "${downloadFunction}"//This works.
    echo "Downloaded"
```

Doing that works, but after the execution the script stop and "Downloaded" it´s never showed. But still the file is downloaded

If I try using $() like

```
    $("${downloadFunction}")
```

The it´s telling me

```
     línea 42: curl -s 'https://foo.com/foo.jar' -o '/bla.jar'': No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

Any idea how to execute a function passed to my main bash as configuration parameter?

Regards

Comment: Maybe you could concatenate both commands, `curl` and `echo` in `downloadFunction`.

Comment: BTW, in general, "parameter" is often read in this kind of context to refer to a command-line argument, either to the script or to a function, hence, the clarification of the text to match the code samples by specifying "configuration parameter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a function definition:

```
downloadFunction="curl -s 'https://foo.com/foo.jar' -o '/bla.jar'"
```

This **is** a function definition:

```
downloadFunction() { curl -s 'https://foo.com/foo.jar' -o '/bla.jar'; }
```

...and you absolutely can define it in that way in a config file being sourced.

---

If you fix your function definition to *actually be a function*, you can call it as so:

```
downloadFunction
```

If you intend to pass a string full of code to be interpreted in the current interpreter, and able to contain arbitrary content (redirections, flow-control, etc), use `eval` to evaluate it:

```
# do this only if the content of the variable has been human-audited and is known
# ...not to be malicious; shell injection vulnerabilities can occur otherwise.
eval "$downloadFunction"
```

If rather than an arbitrary function or a string you intend to pass a single command to be evaluated literally (with no redirections or other shell directives), use an array variable instead, and expand it appropriately:

```
# do this only in special cases -- ie. building up the command incrementally
downloadCommand=( curl -s 'https://foo.com/foo.jar' -o 'bla.jar' )
"${downloadCommand[@]}"
```

For best practices, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 1):

`exec` replaces the current process with a new one and when that process exits, there is no script to return to. It should work as intended if you remove that word.

Edit:

Or if you don't want to start a new bash process at all, simply replace:

```
exec bash -c "${downloadFunction}"//This works.
```

with:

```
eval $downloadFunction
```

Edit 2:

As Charles Duffy correctly pointed out, `eval` is needed. Otherwise word-splitting is performed with quotation marks interpreted literally and passed inside arguments.

Comment: No, calling `$downloadFunction` to invoke an arbitrary string of code stored in a variable by that name does not work reliably. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: ...specifically, calling `$downloadFunction` to execute `curl -s 'https://foo.com/foo.jar' -o '/bla.jar'` won't parse the literal quotes out of the string, but will treat them as literal parts of the command line to pass to `curl`. Thus, it'll run the same command as `curl -s "'https://foo.com/foo.jar'" -o "'/bla.jar'"` -- certainly not what you want.

Comment: You are right! I didn't realize that. Thanks. Adding `eval` should make it work, right?